# parallel port access in C# .net

Tags: c#, .net, hardware

How can i send and receive data though parallel port using C# .net? Also can u guys please explain how to use parallel port to receive data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[I/O Ports Uncensored - 1 - Controlling LEDs (Light Emiting Diodes) with Parallel Port](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/csppleds.aspx?df=100&forumid=21021&exp=0&select=974134)

Comment: i saw this one dude. But I need to know how to control it without help of a dll. I just need to learn it.

Comment: Dude, I don't think .NET has support for the parallel port, so you *have* to go through one of the non-.NET DLLs to use it.

Comment: The inpout32.dll has a kernel driver built into it that it extracts on-demand, that it then makes calls to using a file handle to change the state of the parallel port. You might be able to extract the kernel driver and permanently install it, from there you might be able to figure out the interface between the user-land dll and the kernel driver to call into it yourself.