# send raw command to lpt or com port without installing the device

Tags: c#, serial-port, lpt

is there a way to send raw command like esc+something to print or to open cash drawer through lpt port or com port in c# .net , **but the printer or cash drawer just plugged in and not installed in that computer(using win xp os)** , so there is no printer name as a parameter, just lpt1 or com2 or com2 . Thanks

Thanks

Comment: You'd better focus a bit on how this is going to work on your customer's machine instead of yours.  You wouldn't want to write a bunch of code and then find out it is all junk.  Using something like OPOS is pretty common, it already gives you access to printers and cash drawers like that.

Comment: thanks, i will looking for OPOS , maybe opos is the answer, because i just heard that term for the first time

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to install a driver for COM or LPT peripheral device if it has a real COM or LPT. You have to have just installed drivers for COM or LPT in your PC.
If you have a USB 2 COM adapter, you have to install drivers for it. But as soon as you have a working COM alias like COM1 or COM10, COM11... you can send or recieve characters with no problem if you use a  right configuration for transmission.

Check out [SerialPort class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.aspx).
For parallel port check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032190/parallel-port-access-in-c-sharp-net).